# Graphics Glitch

Tags: macbook-pro, display

https://youtu.be/QQhId1b2ZJU

The issue is highlighted in the video above.

It's on a fresh install of High Sierra.

System info:

```
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
Graphics: Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

AMD Radeon R9 M370X:

  Chipset Model:    AMD Radeon R9 M370X
  Type: GPU
  Bus:  PCIe
  PCIe Lane Width:  x8
  VRAM (Total): 2 GB
  Vendor:   AMD (0x1002)
  Device ID:    0x6821
  Revision ID:  0x0083
  ROM Revision: 113-C5670E-945
  VBIOS Version:    113-C567A1-006
  EFI Driver Version:   01.00.945
  Automatic Graphics Switching: Supported
  gMux Version: 4.0.20 [3.2.8]
  Metal:    Supported, feature set macOS GPUFamily1 v3

Intel Iris Pro:

  Chipset Model:    Intel Iris Pro
  Type: GPU
  Bus:  Built-In
  VRAM (Dynamic, Max):  1536 MB
  Vendor:   Intel
  Device ID:    0x0d26
  Revision ID:  0x0008
  Automatic Graphics Switching: Supported
  gMux Version: 4.0.20 [3.2.8]
  Metal:    Supported, feature set macOS GPUFamily1 v3
  Displays:
Color LCD:
  Display Type: Built-In Retina LCD
  Resolution:   2880 x 1800 Retina
  Framebuffer Depth:    24-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
  Main Display: Yes
  Mirror:   Off
  Online:   Yes
  Rotation: Supported
  Automatically Adjust Brightness:  No
```